# Gradle- Error while compiling (IN-APP BILLING)

Tags: java, android, gradle

Hello everyone im getting this error while trying to compile my project on android studio

Error:Execution failed for task :app:compileDebugAidl.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
>    Error while executing process C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aidl.exe with 
>    arguments {-pC:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\framework.aidl...

My gradle settings are:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 25`
```